# Maven command for clover issue

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, clover

Hi all I am using Clover to generate the code covarage report but it is always showing 0% code covarage. In sonar.sh file I run below command

sonar.sh file below

```
rm -f ${M2_HOME}/conf/settings.xml
cp /code/settings.xml ${M2_HOME}/conf/settings.xml 
chmod 644 ${M2_HOME}/conf/settings.xml
#mvn package
#mvn -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -s ./settings.xml -U test -Dclover=true
mvn -X -Dmaven.wagon.http.ssl.insecure=true -U -s ./settings.xml clean -U package -U test -Dclover=true
mvn clean verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=<sonar URL>
```

Pom.xml file

```
<properties>
<clover.version>4.2.1</clover.version>
<properties>



reporting>
        <excludeDefaults>true</excludeDefaults>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.openclover</groupId>
                    <artifactId>clover-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <!--cloverDatabase>${project.build.directory}/target/clover/cloverMerge.db</cloverDatabase-->
                        <generateHtml>false</generateHtml>
                        <generatePdf>false</generatePdf>
                        <generateXml>true</generateXml>
                        <generateHistorical>false</generateHistorical>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </reporting>
    
        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openclover</groupId>
        <artifactId>clover</artifactId>
        <version>${clover.version}</version>
    </dependency>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.openclover</groupId>
            <artifactId>clover-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${clover.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <setTestFailureIgnore>true</setTestFailureIgnore>
                <includesTestSourceRoots>false</includesTestSourceRoots>
                <targetPercentage>0%</targetPercentage>
                <debug>true</debug>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>setup</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>aggregate</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clover</goal>
                         <goal>report</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I did the googled, and found I have to set targat folder path where xml has generated. But I am not sure, where I have to put this url(target/site/clover/clover.xml)

Also, I checked below entry do I need to added in setting.xml file

```
<pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>org.openclover</pluginGroup>
</pluginGroups>
```

Please confirm
Can Some one let me know how can run below parameter through maven

-U -s settings.xml -Dsonar.dynamicAnalysis=reuseReports
-Dsonar.clover.reportPath=target/site/clover/clover.xml

Could you please help me because it ia a blocker to me.

Comment: Is the clover configuration/plugin in Sonar enabled/installed?

Comment: Yes all other projects showing. This project only in JDK 11 so we are using Docker. In other projects these above two property added in "Additional Parameters". But in this project we can't add. We have to run Maven command only. So I am not sure how I can run or can add either sonar.sh or pom.xml file. If you can help me it would be more helpful . Thank